# Names queried from mysql database does not display in jQuery Mobile remote autocomplete listview

Tags: javascript, php

I have used the **Remote autocomplete** demo as a basis for my code, however the names from my database do not display within the listview. After I type at least three characters, the error function is called.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <h3>Cities worldwide</h3>
    <p>After you enter <strong>at least three characters</strong> the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.</p>
      <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..." data-filter-theme="c"></ul>   
</div>
```

Help will be much appreciated (I am aware of the lack of validation both on client and server-side but I would like to get the basic functionality working, thank you).

Comment: on of my knowledge you should use type: "GET" in your Ajax.

Comment: update your question with your ajax & php

Comment: @HassanAhmed I have implemented an alternative to this, so help is no longer needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add Post Type in your Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "search.php",
    Type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        term: $input.val()
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, response) {
        alert(textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

Comment: I have made the adjustments suggested but the error still persists.